# How to view list of class loaded by Tomcat during runtime in Windows

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, classpath

I want to see the list of classes loaded by tomcat while startup in windows. Can any body help me with this. I am really stuck.

I have a jar added in the classpath but while during runtime it is complaining noclassdefenitionfounderror. I have printed the classpath value. the relative path to the jar that contains the class is there, still no luck.

Comment: You probably need to add that JAR in `Servers > Open Launch Configuration > Classpath > User Entries > Add Jars`

Comment: How did you add your JAR file to the "classpath"? If you are getting `NoClassDefinitionFoundError`, then listing the loaded classes won't help: your class has obviously not been loaded.